# Javascript error message - "Object required"

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple javascript function by creating a js.AWBTracking.js file.

```
function ChangeExpImpStatus() { 
  var rbtnExport;
  var rbtnImport; 
  rbtnExport = document.getElementById('rbtnExp'); 
  rbtnImport = document.getElementById('rbtnImp'); 
  if(rbtnExport.checked) {
    document.getElementById('lblHAWBNo').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('txtHAWBNo').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('tdAirline').style.display ='block'; 
  } 
  else { 
    document.getElementById('lblHAWBNo').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('txtHAWBNo').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('tdAirline').style.display ='none'; 
  } 
}
```

and in aspx file I wrote,

but whenever I run the project, it shows the error in jsAWBTracking file, "Object required". the error is shown at line,

> document.getElementById('txtHAWBNo').style.display = 'none';

please help me to get out of this... :-(

Comment: check the id of the element if it exist

Comment: i'll second that, check if the element exist or post the part of HTML code where you access the ID

Comment: Dude, for a start you're missing the aspx code, and then you haven't bothered to format the code you do have. Come on: the markdown formatting is simple enough. My first thought is that you've mistyped the id of the element but I can't tell.

Comment: thanks a lot boyetboy, you were right. It is fine now. the id was mistyped in the jsAWBTracking.js file. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good, I am skeptical. Are you trying to execute the script before the the HTML is rendered to the view? Please check when is your script is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the visibility from code behind? Element with visibility false will not render as html so you are getting null object else check the id of the element to see if there is any typo.

Thanks 
Ashwani

Comment: thanks a lot boyetboy, you were right. It is fine now. the id was mistyped in the jsAWBTracking.js file. :-)